# GeometryReader broken after update

Tags: swiftui

I've downloaded the new Xcode 11.4 update and it's broken my codebase. I use GeometryReader to determine the user's Watch screen size so it can draw a frame that fills up most of the frame.

Say if I wrote this to draw a rectangular frame:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader {geometry in
      ZStack {
      // Draw rounded rectangle flashcard background

        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
          .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height*0.9) 
      }
    }
  }
```

It looks fine at the moment. But my main view usually uses subviews more like this:

```
 var body: some View {
    GeometryReader {geometry in
      ZStack {
      // Draw rounded rectangle flashcard background

        Frontside(id: self.$settings.randomNum, sheet: self.$showingSheet, rotate: self.$fullRotation, invis: self.$showNextCard, col: self.$colour, width: geometry.size.width*0.9, height: geometry.size.height).environmentObject(self.settings)
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.showResults ? 180.0 : 0.0), axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0))
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.fullRotation ? 360.0 : 0.0), axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0))
        .opacity(self.showResults ? 0 : 1)
        .zIndex(self.showResults ? 0 : 1)

      }
    }
  }

public struct Frontside: View
{
  @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings

  @Binding public var id: Int
  @Binding public var sheet: Bool
  @Binding public var rotate: Bool
  @Binding public var invis: Bool
  @Binding public var col: Int
  public var width: CGFloat
  public var height: CGFloat

  public var body: some View
  {

    ZStack {
      // Draw rounded rectangle flashcard background
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
        .frame(width: self.width, height: self.height)
        .zIndex(0)
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason this causes an error when I call Frontside. Does anyone know why? There doesn't seem to be a real difference between the two code snippets other than using a subview in the second example.

Comment: are you able to be more specific? "GeometryReader broken after update"  is hard to understand. please, prepare some executable, simplified example we can understand

Comment: try to remove UserSettings (env var) for now and see if it still reproduces

Comment: Still get same error - precondition failure: invalid input index: 2

Comment: I am also getting these same "precondition failure" GeometryReader errors after upgrading to Xcode 11.4 – in code that has been running perfectly for months.

Comment: How do we get to the bottom of this? Should we report it as a bug or has someone managed a workaround?

Comment: Any joy with this?

Comment: None at all, how do we get more people to look into this issue?

Comment: Please file feedbacks to Apple via the Feedback Assistant app (it's installed in every Mac)

Comment: It's been more than a month and still no reply!

Comment: Xcode 12 beta seems to have fixed this issue.